# Insert Pandas with timezone-aware columns as string into SQL Server with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, timezone

I'm struggling in inserting JSON data into SQL Server containing timezone information. I'm aware that the datatype DATETIMEOFFSET will not work. I'm happy to just land the data in a VARCHAR column, where I can later transform it into a true timezone-aware datatype.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, NVARCHAR

json_data = json.dumps([{ "date" : "2019-08-13T11:12:05+02:00"}])
df = pd.read_json(json_data, dtype='object')

con='mssql+pyodbc://database'
engine = create_engine(con, encoding='utf-8', echo=False)

table_name = "load"
columns = {'date': NVARCHAR()}

print(df.dtypes)
df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='replace', dtype=columns, index=False)
```

Whatever I do, I'm always getting "2019-08-13 11:12:05.0000000" as a value in SQL Server.

As you can see, I tried to "persuade" Python to use "object" as the datatype in loading a dataframe and setting NVARCHAR as datatype for the target. Somewhere this is still translated into DATETIME2(7).

Is there a way, I can land that timezone-aware string as a string in SQL Server?

Comment: What is the datatype used for date column of 'load' table in SqlServer?

Comment: nvarchar. The example above auto-creates the table with that data type.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward solution would be to convert the pandas Timestamp column to string before calling `to_sql`:

```python
json_data = json.dumps([{"date": "2019-08-13T11:12:05+02:00"}])
df = pd.read_json(json_data)

# convert pandas Timestamp column to string
df = df.astype({'date': numpy.str})

table_name = "#tmp"
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(f"SELECT * FROM [{table_name}]").fetchall())
    # [('2019-08-13 11:12:05+02:00',)]
```